# why command Truffle init not creating Migrations.sol?

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-contract, solidity-0.8.x

I created new folder in truffle with command

```
truffle init
```

version of truffle and others

```
Truffle v5.5.30 (core: 5.5.30)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity - 0.8.17 (solc-js)
Node v16.16.0
Web3.js v1.7.4
```

but it won't created Migrations.sol file.
contract folder included only .gitkeep file.

Answer (score 0):

truffle unbox work fine
just use truffle unbox